# On a table R(ABCDE) like that, i need a SQL Trigger that prevents when tuple's A and B columns are same but try to give a different value to C

Tags: sql, database, triggers

On the R(ABCDE) table tuples if A and B  are same, then C also same value.  I need a trigger that prevents to violate this rule when  update the table.

[image]

Comment: Are there any keys on A and B?

Comment: No its  exactly like this

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

This question indicates a short-coming in the data model.  If `C` is dependent on `A` and `B`, it should have its own table.  I think the data model needs to be fixed.

You should have an AB table:

```
AB_ID    A     B     C
```

In this table the combination A/B would be unique.

Your table would then remove the three columns `A`, `B`, and `C` and replace them with `AB_ID`.

Voila!  You can model the data correctly and you don't need to use a trigger.

Comment: well the thing is i have to use trigger because i've been asked to do it on this way :(